# Correct way to use Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asynchronous, async-await

I've been working for a few days on a performance problem.
Before I delve deeper I want to quickly explain how the specific service work.

I have a main Service that get a request and send requests to other micro-services but the single Entry Point for the user is to Main service, I thinks is more simple to understand with this image:

[image: Main Service and micro services]

After the Main service get request from API he do some logic, query the Db and then get a list, every item on the list has Id, to get enrichment about every item the main service create request to one of the micro-service.

For example John request main service, main service get from Db a list of 90 items then the main service will create 90 calls to micro service and return to John single response that include 90 items.

Now the question is only about the right way to create async call to micro service.

This how I develop this part:

```
GetDetailsAsync(Id, result.Items, request.SystemComponentId);

private static void GetDetailsAsync(string Id, List<MainItem> items, int systemId)
    {
            var getDetailsTasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach (MainItem single in items)
            {
                    getDetailsTasks.Add(SetSingleDetailsAsync(Id, single, systemId));
            }

            Task.WhenAll(getDetailsTasks);
    }

private static async Task SetSingleDetailsAsync(string Id, MainItem single, int systemId)
{
        single.ActivityExtendedDetails = await ProcessItemDetailsRequest.GetItemDetailsAsync(Id, single.TypeId,
            single.ItemId, systemId);
}

public static Task<JObject> GetItemDetailsAsync(string id, short type,
            string itemId, int systemId)
{
    var typeList = ActivityTypeDetails.GetActivityTypes();
    var url = GetActivityUrl(id, type, itemId, typeList);
    if (url == null)
    {
        throw new Failure($"No url defined for type {type}");
    }

    try
    {
        JObject res;
        using (var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(url).Result)
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            res = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(res);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Warn(
            $"The uri {url} threw exception {ex.Message}.");
        //[Todo]throw exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code run and the result is not good enough, the CPU rises very quickly and becomes very high, I think that I has a problem on GetItemDetailsAsync func because I use client.GetStreamAsync(url).Result
when using .Result  it's block until the task is completed.

So I do some minor change on GetItemDetailsAsync to try to be really async:

```
public static async Task<JObject> GetItemDetailsAsync(string id, short type,
            string itemId, int systemId)
{
    var typeList = ActivityTypeDetails.GetActivityTypes();
    var url = GetActivityUrl(id, type, itemId, typeList);
    if (url == null)
    {
        throw new Failure($"No url defined for type {type}");
    }

    try
    {
        JObject res;
        using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            res = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);
        }
        return res;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Warn(
            $"The uri {url} threw exception {ex.Message}.");
        //[Todo]throw exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

But now I get null where I supposed to get the data that come from Async function.
I try to debugging and I noticed something weird, everything happen likes as I would expect: the methods was called, request to micro-service was executed and get response but the response from the End-Point(which is found on main-service) return before the async method return from micro-service, that cause that I get null instead of my expected data.

I thinks that maybe I don't use correctly async\await and would be happy if anyone could explain how this behavior happens

Comment: Why do you include `Task.WhenAll` without awaiting it?

Comment: This code is not "micro", you can't see the mountain of code in the libraries. Seeing code drive up the CPU load is always a feature and not a bug, the user won't have to wait so long to get results. Your OS is quite capable of dealing with it. If this is all supposed to run in the background and not inconvenience the user then draw fewer boxes, sequence them instead.

Comment: Why are you calling you're microservices 90 times instead of once? Are you hitting your database 90 times?  There are several reasons you could be having performance issues, Quick performance gain `<gcServer enabled="true"/>`,  Did you configure service throttling correctly?  Are you warming up your service or your testing cold, if so there is a bug in wcf and if concurrent calls are made it will spawn the service multiple times.   Did you Open up the thread pool and expand the thread count I/O threads?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Your right, await was missing at this place. It was more changes that I make on my code, but I think that the most important point is when you decide to use async/await you need to cascading effect as async travels up through your code (In my case from my controller API to the most intern function that consider).

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of your procedure that your CPU is hardly waiting for anything? Your procedure is supposed to look for other work as soon as it has to await for something. I'd expect high CPU usage if you hardly wait idly. The work has to be done anyway, and if you do them simultaneously you'll finish earlier at the cost of higher CPU. or am I wrong?